# Is it possible to carry over 20MW?

Tags: power, voltage, current, wire, conductors

Is it possible for a series of conductors carry massive currents(**100 kA**) at voltages over **100V**?
Assuming there is massive cooling.
How can power plants carry MegaWatts of power?

Comment: They can carry Gigawatts and commonly do so.

Comment: at super high voltages and as low current as possible, for less loss and heat and explosions. Also, the transmission is done with "max power transfer" by having the transmitter and receiving end with matched impedences, but still as little "resistance" as possible. Imagine transferring thousands of Amperes though copper cables.. You would have a fire hazard for sure! As an understatement..

Comment: @KyranF Not if the copper cables are fat enough.

Comment: @arne, yeah, they have to be huge - that is expensive, copper cabling is ridiculously expensive, and heavy, and just physically silly. :D. Would be like twisted conduits 1-2 metres thick

Comment: You could use a super conductor to get infinite amps, but then your voltage is zero...

Comment: A superconductor actually can't carry infinite amps by the way..

Power plants deliver hundreds of MW by upping the voltage. For example, if the power plant delivered 20MW @ 230kV, then its only ~87A. Often though for really high power outputs the voltage is higher than that.

Comment: Power lines don't transfer high currents because that would melt the cables or at least waste energy as heat. Instead, they transfer high voltage (50,000 V) and then use transformers to reduce the voltage to the desired level and get higher current accordingly.

Comment: However, is it possible to carry high current(100 kA+) at low voltages(100V+)? Or it would never work? What could be the limit for copper conductors?

Comment: If you put no constraints on the size of the conductor then you can carry as much current as you want. At any voltage you like (since you haven't specified a reference point for the voltage or a physical arrangement of conductors). Without some practical constraints this question is nonsensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power plants do have buses which carry large amounts of current, but they do so at as high a voltage as is practical. This is because the power losses in a conductor are equal to the square of the current times the resistance:
$$P_{loss}=I^{2}R_{wire}$$

For the whole circuit, we know that:
$$I=\frac{P_{total}}{V_{source}}$$

So, for constant power, the circuit current is inversely proportional to the voltage. If you sub that into the first equation and do some handwaving, we learn that
$$P_{loss}\propto \frac{1}{V^{2}}$$

Therefore, losses are inversely proportional to the *square* of the voltage, so if you double the voltage, your copper losses get cut down to a quarter. Since in order to decrease the resistance of a wire you have to increase its cross-sectional area, this can be a huge savings in conductor cost. It might not be so big in, say, a small factory, but when you're dealing with megawatts the savings quickly add up.

There's another reason to use high voltage, too. The [skin effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) means that at mains frequency the majority of current will only flow in the outside 8mm or so of a conductor. Thus, very high current buses aren't actually solid chunks of copper or aluminum. They're actually hollow pipes. You might have also seen transmission lines with multiple wires per phase - this is, again, because of the skin effect.

So, as for your question - yes, power plant buses can carry a *lot* of power. I did an internship at a large hydroelectric station where each generator had a 12 kV bus with a typical figure of about 8 kA per phase (these were 300 MW units). As it's not practical to carry this much current very far, it was converted up to 500 kV at the outdoor substation for transmision. The buses were hollow pipes as mentioned above, which were in other larger grounded pipes to isolate their (significant) magnetic fields from other equipment. Of course, this pales in comparison to nuclear plants, where 1000 MW units are considered typical.

Comment: I was at [DNV-GL/KEMA](http://www.dnvkema.com/services/testing/labs/HPL.aspx) ("the world’s largest independent testing and certification lab for medium, high and ultra-high voltage electrical infrastructure components") the other day, they are not particularly impressed about 8kA currents. I believe it is at the lower end of their scale.

Comment: That would be correct. This particular plant had a bunch of small units (ten of 'em) rather than, say, five 600 MW units. Different design philosophy, and a bit of maintenance nightmare.

Comment: However, is it possible to carry high current(100 kA+) at low voltages(100V+)? Or it would never work?

Comment: You certainly could, with a big enough busbar (more practically, with several busbars in parallel). It's just not practical for most applications. If you want, you can easily do the math to find out exactly how big they'd need to be - choose a length, compute the skin depth at your AC frequency, decide on an "acceptable" amount of loss, and work out your cross sectional area based on the resistivity of copper. From there, you can figure out how big a hollow bus bar will be. It will be very big.

Comment: @freyyr Pretty sure it would, I mean carrying that amount of high DC current with large voltages, Im expecting this bar being above a ton... easily.

Comment: DC is is a little better (and easier) as you don't have to worry about the skin effect. Still, the result will be quite large.

Comment: @Key The size of the conductor is __NOT__ influenced by the voltage on the conductor. The size of the conductor __IS__ determined by the magnitude of the current. (Ignoring mechanical issues, weight, etc.)

Comment: @JoeHass Right, but wouldn't a larger conduct be better so that the resistance would be much less, thus the powerless and heat generated would be lower. I mean 100V+ and 100kA + is A LOT of power and A LOT of current that thing would be EXTREMELY hot!

Comment: @Key The 100V is the voltage of the conductor with respect to ground. This voltage does not determine the power dissipated __in the conductor__. For that you need the voltage drop that actually occurs __across the conductor__. And your question said to "assume massive cooling", so heating was not an issue.

Comment: Oh yes. I was assuming otherwise...

Comment: @JoeHass If there we're enormous losses(1MW or more) can it still be cooled? That's extremely hot!

Comment: @Key It's only __hot__ if the conductor is small. If you spread that power over a very (very!) large conductor then it just warms up a bit. Your question put __NO RESTRICTION__ on the size of the conductor and assumed __MASSIVE COOLING__ so why are you now throwing heat and temperature into it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Generally high power is carried at as high a voltage as possible.  This minimizes the current thru the wire to carry the same power.  This is why long distance high power transmission lines are in the 500 kV to 1 MV range.

Comment: Yes, but what about 100 **kA** @ **100V**? The point  I'm emphasizing is having large currents with reasonable voltages like 100V and above.

Comment: @Key You are confusing the voltage of the conductor __with respect to ground__ and the voltage __across__ the conductor. Olin is talking about high voltage with respect to ground. To calculate power loss in the conductor you need to know the voltage drop along the conductor itself.

Comment: @Key: 100 kA would require massively thick cable that would be very expensive, not only the cable itself but also whatever has to support the weight.  Your 100 kA at 100 V is 10 MW.  The same 10 MW can be carried more economically at say 500 kV and 20 A.  Converting to and from high voltage at each end adds some expense, but this is offset by the much cheaper cable and infrastructure over any reasonable distance that a power plant would be sending its power.